# Laravel Eloquent groupBy

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How to use Laravel Eloquent with groupBy?

This is my code but I got errors all the time:

```
Message::whereColumn('host_id', 'sender_id')
                ->groupBy('host_id')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(10);
```

The error message is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'project_db.messages.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `messages` where
>   `host_id` = `sender_id` group by `host_id` order by `created_at` desc
>   limit 10 offset 0)

What I'm trying to achieve is display messages as branches (groups), threads.

Comment: try `->groupBy(['host_id', 'sender_id'])`

Comment: I don't have a clue about laravel, but for me a select * grouping by just one column looks weird (maybe the table has just that column, but it doesn't seem that...)

Comment: Column `sender_id` is a non aggregate function Either use it in group by clause or don't use strict mode by adding `strict => false` in `config/database.php` file

Comment: try by dividing `whereColumn()` like `select` and `where` functions.Like `Message::select('host_id, sender_id'')->where('condition')`

Comment: This isn't a laravel specific issue. As of MySQL 5.7 the behaviour for `GROUP BY` changed. There is more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql

Comment: If you give a little bit more information about what you're going to be doing with the data from this query then there is probably a workaround / alternative that can be provided :)

Comment: You can disable `only_full_group_by` sql mode following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322222/laravel-eloquent-orm-group-where